# Aurelia-http-client 404 not found

Tags: jspm, aurelia

I am trying to follow this tutorial but I am having import issues for aurelia-http-client.js.

Overview:
Working in Visual Studio Asp.Net 5 project. Through jspm I installed aurelia-framework and aurelia-bootstrapper.

```
jspm install aurelia-framework
jspm install aurelia-bootstrapper
```

I wanted my app.js to be included in a different folder than my root so:

```
<div aurelia-app>
    <script src="~/jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="~/config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.config({
            "paths": {
                "*": "js/aurelia/*.js"
            }
        });
        System.import("aurelia-bootstrapper");
    </script>
</div>
```

Now all seems fine it load app.js from the proper folder. I now need to use the aurelia-router so:

```
import {Router} from "aurelia-router";

export class App {
    static inject() { return [Router]; }

    constructor(router) {
        this.router = router;
        this.router.configure(config => {
            config.title = "Reddit";

            config.map([
              {route: ["", "funny"], moduleId: "funny", nav: true, title: "Funny Subreddit"},
              {route: "gifs", moduleId: "gifs", nav: true, title: "Gifs Subreddit"}
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

There is where it blows up...I believe router is trying to grab `aurelia http client` because my console throws up with a `404 -> http://localhost:53342/js/aurelia/aurelia-http-client.js`...Which I am curious why its looking in /js/aurelia for aurelia-http-client in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought `aurelia-framework` included `aurelia-http-client` it did not. `jspm install aurelia-http-client` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be [a new version](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation) of skeleton navigation template for [ASP.NET 5](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-es2016-asp.net5)...

System.js is usually configured via separate `config.js` file. [Here's the one](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/skeleton-es2016-asp.net5/src/skeleton-navigation-es2016-vs/wwwroot/config.js) from skeleton application. Note that it also has paths for jspm packages:

```
paths: {
    "*": "js/aurelia/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
}
```

You might need to correct those paths to be relative to your application root.